# Map roles from Keycloak Client Role to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, keycloak

I’m currently using Keycloak as my SSO and have a working integration with Jenkins.

In Jenkins I have also installed and configured the Role Based Strategy plugin that allows me to limit access within Jenkins based on a users role.

This all works as expected. However, right now I have to manually configure these user roles from the Jenkins UI.

What I would like to do is have client roles in Keycloak map to their respective roles in Jenkins.

I can’t seem to find any documentation or answers on here on how to do this.

Any guidance ?